# USB-C charging issues - ASUS Q325UA

Tags: usb, power-management, laptop, battery

Linux 4.15.0-23-generic x86_64
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Charging works... but certain conditions leads to difficulty getting it registered as plugged in to charge. I think I narrowed it down to one repeatable case. Not sure how to further debug to create a bug report for Ubuntu or Linux.

Scenarios:

1. On and plugged in: charges
2. Off and plugged in: charges
3. Plugged in then standby: charges
4. Standby then plugged in: does not charge

Can anyone help me narrow this down?

Comment: Has to be running to start the charger?

Comment: Well, if it is powered off, it works fine. If it is in sleep mode with lid closed, it does not.

Comment: I assume usb-c has some sort of negotiation period before charging is accepted, and there may be some bug with it in certain operating conditions